# How to set Sample time for all components within a subsystem?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a subsystem I am trying to make, and within this subsystem is a discrete filter block. I am trying to place a mask over the subsystem, and have it so the dialog will set the sampling rate of the discrete filter block. Is this possible and how? The subsystem can be seen on the left & the contents within it are on the right.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [Documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/managing-sample-times-in-subsystems.html) about how the sampling rate works for subsystems, also take a look at [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/types-of-sample-time.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you make the subsystem atomic with a sample time and then all blocks inside use inherited sample time it should work.

You can also use a sample time parameter on all blocks inside the subsystem and set that variable fom the mask.